# C++: using class with explicit operator bool overloaded

Tags: c++, c++11

**Context:**

I have a class with an internal boolean value that seems like a good candidate for overloading *operator bool*, like this:

```
class MyBool{

    private:
    bool value_ = false;

    // Nice API and logic to set the interal value_ to true or false...

    public: 
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return value_;
    };

};
```

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion, "Contextual conversions" section, this works in:

- the controlling expression of if, while, for;
- the operands of the built-in logical operators !, && and ||;
- the first operand of the conditional operator ?:;
- the predicate in a static_assert declaration;
- the expression in a noexcept specifier;

Which explains why I get errors when trying to use it in other ways, like this:

```
MyBool x;  
///...
bool y = x; // --> error: cannot convert ‘MyBool’ to ‘bool’ in initialization 
// or:
bool z; 
z = x;      // --> error: cannot convert ‘MyBool’ to ‘bool’ in assignment

// Or returning from a function:
bool func(...){
     MyBool x;
     // ...
     return x; // --> error: cannot convert ‘MyBool’ to ‘bool’ in return
}

// Or in Gtests, like:
MyBool x;
// ...
EXPECT_TRUE(x); // --> error: no matching function for call to ‘testing::AssertionResult::AssertionResult(MyBool)’
```

If I removed the *explicit* keyword, some problems cold arise because of implicit conversions (safe bool idiom in pre C++11: http://blog.asymptotic.co.uk/2014/03/the-safe-bool-idiom-in-c/).

In these cases, I could explicitly cast the *MyBool* variable to bool and it would work, but to me, this non-homogeneous use kind of defeats the purpose of overloading the operator, that is: to be able to naturally use *MyBool* as a bool. Instead, I could add a member function like this:

```
bool get_value() const {
    return value_;
}
```

And use x.get_value() every time I need to "cast" to bool, even in the conditions, loops, etc.

**The question is**: is there a way to use this class in the cases above, or some of them, with modifications to the class code only (not the calling code), and without removing the *explicit* keyword?
(Preferrably in C++11).

Comment: It seems to me that you *want* implicit conversions for `MyBool`. In which cases *don't* you want implicit conversions?

Comment: You can't have implicit conversions with `explicit` keyword. If you want to keep `explicit`, then do `(bool)x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems to be how to both (1) have implicit conversion to bool and (2) avoid integer promotion/conversion. Delete the conversion to `int`:

```
class MyBool
{
public: 
    operator bool() const
    {
        return value_;
    };

    operator int() const = delete;

private:
    bool value_ = false;
};
```

All of the lines in the question now compile because implicit conversion is allowed. And none of the safe-bool problems compile because integer conversion is deleted:

```
MyBool x;
int i = x;
x << 1;
x < 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, works as expected. WRT @bolov answer, it seems that forbids implicit conversion to int, but no other types, so is it possible that this would still have some unintended consequences (that would be avoidable by the *explicit* approach)?

Comment: @Milo if you try to convert to another integer type (like `long` or `short`) you get a "conversion is ambiguous" error. Not a relevant error message, but at least it's an error.

Comment: An implicit conversion from `MyBool` to a non-`bool`, non-`int` integral type `T` can use the user-defined conversion to `bool` followed by integral conversion to `T`, or the user-defined conversion to `int` followed by integral conversion to `T`. Neither of these is better, so it is ambiguous.

Comment: It is also possible to SFINAE the conversion operator in C++11 (better error message "use of deleted function", but may be more difficult to get right): `template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type> operator T() const = delete;`

Comment: @bolov's answer would be equivalent to SFINAE against `std::is_convertible<T, bool>`. It differs from SFINAE against `std::is_arithmetic<T>` or `operator int = delete` by also disallowing conversion to types which themselves are convertible to `bool` (say, `OtherBool`). This doesn't suffer the safe-bool problem directly because C++ won't combine two user-defined conversions implicitly. Both answers have their place.

Answer (score 4):

C++20 version of deleting all the conversion operators that would in turn implicitly convert to bool:

```
#include <concepts>

class MyBool
{
private:
    bool value_ = false;

public: 
    explicit operator bool() const { return value_; };

    template <std::convertible_to<bool> T>
    operator T() = delete;
};
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Seems to be similar to @Jeff Garret answer. I am using C++11, though (I edited the question accordingly).